# $U$-statistics and their limiting distributions

Tags: self-study, inference, nonparametric, joint-distribution, u-statistics

1. Let $X_1,X_2, . . . ,X_n$ be i.i.d. observations from a continuous distribution
   $F$. Consider the parametric function $\mathbb{P}([\text{min}(X_1,X_2) > X3])$. Find the U-Statistics and its limiting distribution.
   $$$$
2. Let $(X_1, Y_1), (X_2, Y_2), . . . (X_n, Y_n)$ be i.i.d pairs from a bivariate distribution $F(x, y)$. Let $\bar{F}(x, y) = P[X_1 > x,Y_1 > y]$.For the parametric function $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[\bar{F}(x, y)-\bar{F_1}(x)\bar{F_2}(y)]dF_1(x)dF_2(y)$$ find the limiting distribution of the $U$-statistic estimators under the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent  where $\bar{F_1}(x)=\mathbb{P}(X_1>x)$ and $\bar{F_2}(y)=\mathbb{P}(Y_1>y)$.
   $$$$For the $1^{st}$ question we can write $$\mathbb{P}(\text{min}(X_1, X_2)>X_3)=\mathbb{P}(X_1>X_3, X_2>X_3)=\mathbb{P}(X_1>X_3)-\mathbb{P}(X_1>X_3>X_2)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{3}$$ because $X_{i_s}$ are iid continuous random variables. So the kernel would be a constant function with degree 1 say $h(x_1)=\frac{1}{3}$ and the corresponding $U$-statistic would be a degenerate random variable i.e $U_n(X_1, ...., X_n)=\frac{1}{3}$ and so its limiting distribution would again be a degenerate random variable taking the value $\frac{1}{3}$ with probability $1$.
   $$$$For the $2^{nd}$ question under the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are independent we have $$\bar{F}(x, y)=\mathbb{P}(X_1>x, Y_1>y)=\mathbb{P}(X_1>x)\mathbb{P}(Y_1>y)=\bar{F_1}(x)\bar{F_2}(y)$$ and so the given parametric function is the zero function. So again the kernel would be  constant function of degree 1 and the corresponding $U$-statistic would be a degenerate random variable taking the value $0$ with probability $1$.
   $$$$Are the arguments given above correct or is something fishy there?

Comment: As an aside it would be nice to know why limiting distributions are of interest in this context.

Comment: In what sense is the integral in (2) a "parametric function" (it's evidently a *number* and no parameters have been mentioned) and what does it mean for random variables to be "independent for" it?

Comment: @whuber For the 2nd question $X$ and $Y$ were not independent, we only had to find the $U$- statistics but we had to find the limiting distribution when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I don't know. It was just a part of a question.

Comment: Right: but what do the terms I quoted even *mean?*

Comment: Sorry "independent for" doesn't mean anything. I've edited the question.

Comment: And what does "parametric" mean here?

Comment: @whuber That is what I'm asking when the parametric function under consideration is a constant then how to find the U statistics and it's limiting distribution.

Comment: The term "parametric function" has no apparent meaning in this context.  In fact, this expression is a good example of a *non-parametric* family of *distributions.*  A a function of $F,$ no parameters are evident. // As to your question, all estimators are estimating some fixed numerical property of the underlying distribution.  As you have noted, that property is zero under the independence assumption: but that does not imply the estimators themselves are always zero -- nor does it even imply the limiting distribution is zero (although one would hope it is).

Comment: @whuber So then what will be the $U$-statistics in question 1 and 2?

Comment: What would be the $U$ statistic corresponding to $U(X_1,X_2,X_3)=1$ when $X_3 \lt \min(X_1,X_2)$ and $U(X_1,X_2,X_3)=0$ otherwise?  How would it be distributed? How would this distribution change as $n$ increases?

Comment: @whuber The distribution will be independent of $n$ right? And it's asymptotic distribution will be the same?

Comment: If you're unsure, perform some simulations with varying values of $n.$  The process of writing the code often clarifies the underlying mathematical ideas.

Comment: @whuber I'm unsure that's why I'm asking you. In my opinion the $U$-statistics should be constant and so is their asymptotic distribution but I just want to confirm whether this is correct or is there some other way of finding $U$-statistics. Can you please tell me, whatever I've done is correct or not for both the question?

Comment: Right: It does look like you're unsure and my suggestions are motivated by helping you become more sure :-).